# API monitoring using Tyk.io

Tags: api, health-monitoring, tyk

I need to build an API health monitoring system using Tyk.io, to basically check number of requests, latency, errors and produce simple reports. At the moment I am only supposed to focus on this layer, while I will be using something like PostMan to simulate the frontend and some open source APIs on the other side (which will be later replaced by real micro-services). I have installed Tyk.io on Vagrant in local, but not sure how to go from there. So, any hints or pointers are welcome!

Comment: For the developer who downvoted my question: it would be very useful to get your comment along with your vote, so that you could contribute to the discussion from your interesting point of view. Going around, hitting downvote and hiding is such an unprofessional behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

[Tyk](http://docs.tyk.io) can definitely do what you want. I would just start building out your requirements slowly in terms of the functionality for your project i.e. what kind of authorization you want etc
I'd just experiment and start proxying your traffic through the Tyk API Gateway to your upstream APIs and use resources such as the [Tyk docs](http://docs.tyk.io) or the [Tyk Community Forum](http://community.tyk.io). You will hopefully get a handle on things more as you get used to the way the API gateway functions :)

If you get your first api set up using the [tutorials](https://tyk.io/docs/get-started/with-tyk-on-premise/tutorials/tyk-on-premise-pro/create-api/) and set the upstream url as your API then that is a good starting point.